# mobile version of wordpress site without changing themes how to modifie it css

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, version

hello i was trying to give wordpress site css so it use it for diffrent devices 
my work works for Pc's and tablet but fails for phone 
the phone refuses to load css i have given it to load
Css i use :

```css
/*headercover*/
body.has-header-image .custom-header-media img, .has-header-video .custom-header-media video, .has-header-video .custom-header-media iframe, .has-header-image:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page):not(.home) .custom-header-media img {
 
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 
 
 min-height: initial;
}
.home #content.custom-header-media {
 height: 45vw ;
  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 467px) {
.home.custom-header-media {
  
   height: 50px !important;
 }

 .home.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-image.home.blog .custom-header, .has-header-video.home.blog .custom-header {
  height: 10vw;
  margin-top: -138px;
 }

 .home.logged-in .wp-custom-header img {
  margin-top: 138px;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width:467px) {
.home.custom-header-media {
  
   height: 50px !important;
 }

 .home.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-image.home.blog .custom-header, .has-header-video.home.blog .custom-header {
  height: 10vw;
  margin-top: -188px !important;
 }

 .home.logged-in .wp-custom-header img {
  margin-top: 188px !important;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 35px) and (min-width: 0px) and (max-height: 350px) {
.home.custom-header-media {
 
   height: 50px !important;
 }

 .home.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-image.home.blog .custom-header, .has-header-video.home.blog .custom-header {
  height: -150vw;
  margin-top: -188px !important;
 }

 .home.logged-in .wp-custom-header img {
  margin-top: 0px !important ;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 250px)and (min-width: 35px) and (max-height: 480px) {
.home.custom-header-media {
 
   height: 50px !important;
 }

 .home.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-image.home.blog .custom-header, .has-header-video.home.blog .custom-header {
  height: 10vw;
  margin-top: -240px !important;
 }

 .home.logged-in .wp-custom-header img {
  margin-top: 240px !important ;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 280px) and (max-height: 480px) {
.home.custom-header-media {
 
   height: 50px !important;
 }

 .home.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-image.home.blog .custom-header, .has-header-video.home.blog .custom-header {
  height: 10vw;
  margin-top: -240px !important;
 }

 .home.logged-in .wp-custom-header img {
  margin-top: 240px !important ;
 }
}
```

it just seems  weird to me how it works on customizer and not in phones (it works perfectly if i login the phone )
so i was thinking if there is a css code for twentyseventeen wordpress theme for phones which i can change and let it use my css version

Comment: is there some kind of caching in this wordpress ? or did you publish your changes to the css ? it sounds like you get some kind of "editing" state if you login or change stuff and if you are not logged in you get the live version

Comment: yeah  i am not really sure  if i got caching i usually clear cache with wp fastest cache , yeah i prefer to use the edited version for the none login visiters .